# Listening to a change of a textarea

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea

I am looking to listen to the change of a textarea - the text area is hidden and not updated by a user directly, it is updated indirectly by another action.

As far as I can tell the change event is only fired when the focus is removed - In my case the focus never happens. How should I be monitoring the change of the textarea? - **Note I am not using a JS library.**

Comment: Can you not just fire a function when you input the data...

Comment: In my case the updating of the textarea is in another JS file which I can't update :(

Comment: Then I do not think it is possible. After reading the specs i'm sure of it. There will be no event fired (consistently) if there is no user input (the textarea is muted)

Comment: Also, Why can't you alter the other file? if it's not hosted by you download the source and stop referencing the *stupid* one.

Comment: @rlemon !! haha :)  I completely agree... it'd be a good idea to find a more elegant solution than to try to hack around the existing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use a js library, the best way maybe to use the setInterval and Timing features, and simply check textarea at some interval.

Here is a link that may help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: This seems Extreamly hacky (albeit it probably is the only solution given the constraints).

Comment: Yes, very hacky, especially if the update could be happening at a very short time period.  This would then require the interval to be very short and in turn, cause a strain on resources.  Personally, I'd try to find a different solution.

Comment: I love the "Here is the answer... but please don't do this" answers =P

Comment: Hahah.... well, without a full understanding of whats going on, I try to work within what I have been given.  Many solutions for the same problem, some good, some not so good :)